# Securing rest API for android application using spring security

Tags: android, rest, spring-security

I am new to android and spring security. Could you please provide me and example where spring security framework is used.

My requirement once the user is authenticated he will be sent token and he needs to use that token for subsequent calls.

Answer (score 0):

I strongly recommend you to follow this tutorial.

http://technicalrex.com/2015/02/20/stateless-authentication-with-spring-security-and-jwt

I was able to implement this token authentication in my company with only a bit of experience setting Spring Security platforms.

It follows the JWT standard and it's very easy to understand. I hope this would help you!!